# camel is taking too long to get the http response

Tags: apache-camel

I am using camel to orchestrate web service calls to multiple rest endpoint. I am using multicast to send the request params and creating headers for each webservice in different routes and using recepientList to call dynamic url. But looks like the whole process is taking too long. 
There is minimal processing of service responses so that doesnt take more than 100ms.

Here is the first multicast route:

```
from("direct:getCustomer")
        .multicast().shareUnitOfWork().parallelProcessing().streaming()
        .aggregationStrategy(txnAggregator)
        .executorService(exeServiceForRest)
        .to("direct:RouteA", "direct:RouteB", "direct:RouteC");
```

There are 8 routes where this msg will be multicasted.
2 of those routes are making another multicast call to another web service based on the response.

```
from("direct:routeA")
        .process(orderReqBuilder)
        .streamCaching()
        .recipientList(header("url"))
        .multicast().shareUnitOfWork().parallelProcessing().streaming()
        .executorService(exeServiceForRest)
        .aggregationStrategy(txnAggregator)
        .to("direct:subRouteA", "direct:subRouteB");
```

The max response time of all 8 routes is 400ms. And the max response time of these subRoute web services is 300 ms
So the overall response time should be `400(level 1 service calls) + 300(level2 servicer calls) + some computation time(~100 ms) = 900 ms`
but it is taking around 2 sec to complete. 
Moreover, in the logs I found :

```
WMPLTFMLOG420420    1501782127187   2017-08-03 10:42:07.187 when the msg comes to header builder class

WMPLTFMLOG420420    1501782127362   2017-08-03 10:42:07.362 applog.cls=org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpComponent,applog.mthd=createConnectionManager,applog.line=322,applog.msg=Created ClientConnectionManager org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager@77809ca2
```

So there is almost 200ms spent in creating the url and sending the request, I guess. Why is it happening?
Overall, how can I improve the performance in this case. I test this on 4 core machine.
Camel version 2.18.3 and I am using http4 component.

Comment: So how did you come up with the 100ms computation time? Where does the max response time of all 8 routes is 400ms comes from? Are you starting the route then measuring once stopping and then starting? Or did you start a load test which runs for a while and you use the average? Have you tested the REST points with SOAP UI and compared the times? Did you run a profile of the hardware? Is there memory pressure? Is the hard drive not keeping up with IO.

Comment: I did the load test on various endpoints I am hitting in 8 routes. Took an avg. Also, in each processor I logged the starting and completion time.